# division 8086/8087 1/3 =3?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, fpu, x87

I´m having a huge problem using `fdiv`!!!! I'm trying to divide `1/3` so this is what I do

```
.model small
.stack 100h 
.data 

var1 dd 1
var2 dd 3 
var3 dd 2
resultado dt 0.0

.code 

mov ax,@data 
mov ds,ax 
finit 
fild var1
fild var2
fdiv
fstp resultado
ffree 

.exit
```

As you can see I move the result to `resultado` because I can't see the result in `st(0)` (I'm using tasm so I just can see variables in the debugger) the result should be `3EAAAA3A` but I'm getting `40400000`... that's `3`!!! how is it possible?? I tried exchanging variables and nothing!!! Can you help me?? =(

Comment: Show us the actual code or assemble and link the actual code. There's `END` missing at the end of the shown code. If `END` is not in your ASM file, TASM will likely fail to produce a new .OBJ file out of this .ASM file and so you may be linking, executing and debugging a program that you assemblied some time in the past when it had `END` in it. Also, `FSTP` in this code stores 10 bytes, not 4. This may be explained by the same problem with `END`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the FPU is as old as a 8087 you have to put a `fwait` instruction after the `fdiv`. Otherwise you may read a result from the FPU while the FPU is still executing the division and the result you write back is undefined.

This 'feature' has been removed in the 80287 FPU.

Comment: TASM inserts `FWAIT` automatically when compiling the above code.

Comment: @AlvaroFallas: mark the answer that helped as **the** answer.

Answer (score 1):

The presented code does not exhibit the stated problem. It calculates 0.3(3) with `FDIV` (it's actually `FDIVP ST(1), ST`, so it divides ST(1)=1.0 by ST(0)=3.0) and then stores it as as a sequence of 10 bytes (AB AA AA AA AA AA AA AA FD 3F) into `resultado`.